# Open GL Lib Freeglut3 is not installing on my system.Gives the error unable to locate package freeglut3-dev

Tags: opengl

$ sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package freeglut3-dev

Answer (score 2):

First, run the following command to enable the "Universe" repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Next, update `apt` and install `freeglut3-dev` by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install freeglut3-dev
```